# Create bootable USB

Tags: usb, bootable, syslinux

In need of some clarification from the instructions provided by this site:

https://tecadmin.net/how-to-create-bootable-linux-usb-drive-from-linux-terminal/

I was able to successfully follow your instructions until I got to make USB bootable.  Now the only roadblock that I am running up against is the command for make bootable USB. An error message is displayed, it reads:

```
no directory slots | syslinux: failed to create ldlinux.sys
```

Any thoughts on this? The host laptop that is being used is lubuntu, the iso image that was copied is ubuntu v16.04 and the USB drive is 8 GB (fat file system type).

Comment: Welcome to U&L . What is the format of your USB drive?

Comment: What command are you running? You're just showing us the error but not the command. Please make sure your question is self-contained. Don't expect people to click on random links in order to understand what you need.

Comment: @terdon the *Make USB Bootable* step : `sudo syslinux -s /dev/sdd1`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add extra information. Comments are easy to miss, hard to read and can be deleted without warning.

Comment: Also, we need to see *all* the commands you ran and their output. for instance, how can we know if `/dev/sdd1` is the right device file if you haven't shown us the commands you used?

Answer (score 1):

Only a guess: It is possible that the command: **syslinux -s /dev/sdd1** has failed because the partition on the USB drive is formatted with NTFS.

In this case, you should try to re-format the partition with FAT32, with a command like **mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdd1** and start with the instructions again.